# XAML XPath Binding, DataGrid + ComboBox With Xml

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I could really use some assistance on this.  The combo-box is working like I want it to by showing the Xml data.  The data-grid is working as far as pulling the single record from the Xml data.  What I am trying to do is the following that I’m struggling with.

- Make is so that when the combo-box item is chosen, it changes the Xpath of the datagrid to show that schedule.

I’ve played with multiple things such as multi-binding, but I just can’t seem to get it to work properly.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <Window.Resources>

      <!-- Data. -->
           <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Schedules" XPath="Schedules">
             <x:XData>
               <Schedules xmlns="">
                 <Schedule Id="0" Name="Week-1"  Saturday="0" Sunday="0" Monday="7.5" Tuesday="7.5" Wednesday="7.5" Thursday="7.5" Friday="7.5" />
                 <Schedule Id="1" Name="Week-2"  Saturday="0" Sunday="0" Monday="7.5" Tuesday="7.5" Wednesday="7.5" Thursday="7.5" Friday="7.5" />
                 <Schedule Id="2" Name="Week-3"  Saturday="7.5" Sunday="7.5" Monday="7.5" Tuesday="7.5" Wednesday="7.5" Thursday="0" Friday="0" />
               </Schedules>
             </x:XData>
           </XmlDataProvider>


    </Window.Resources>
        
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
          <ComboBox Name="SchedulesComboBox" Width="200" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=//Schedule/@Name, Source={StaticResource Schedules}}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
          <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" Margin="0, 25, 0, 0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=//*[@Id\=\'1\'], 
              Source={StaticResource Schedules}, IsAsync=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Schedule" Width="200" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Saturday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Saturday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sunday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Sunday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Monday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Monday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tuesday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Tuesday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wednesday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Wednesday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thursday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Thursday}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Friday" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Friday}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
          </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with XPath, the only tip that i can give is to use a ViewModel, bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox to the viewmodel and bind the DataGrid.ItemsSource to some derived property in the viewmodel.

Or is this not an option?